# Rows are not affected when comparing datetime column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE       Production
SET          mylocalcol = '22/4/2016 06:13:55 AM'
WHERE        (LocalCol = '2016-04-18 11:51:00 AM ')
```

`mylocalcol` datatype is `nvarchar` and `LocalCol` datatype is `datetime`.

When I execute above query, it will affect the row ie 2518 row

but when I am executing this .. after 2518 ie 2519

```
UPDATE       Production
SET          mylocalcol = '22/4/2016 06:13:55 AM'
WHERE        (LocalCol = '2016-04-18 11:56:29 AM ')
```

zero rows are affected

Comment: Don't mix different date formats. Stick to ANSI format when programming. (You can use other format only for user input/output.)

Comment: This is the reason to use correct data types. Use `DATETIME` or other datetime formats when storing datetimes.

Comment: can you suggest datatypes

Comment: Are you sure you have the accurate value there? What do you get when you `SELECT 1 FROM Production WHERE LocalCol = '2016-04-18 11:56:29 AM '`?

Comment: ya I am sure about it...

Comment: i get output as 0 Rows are affected

Comment: Are you storing milliseconds in LocalCol? What result did you get running the SELECT query I previously suggested?

Comment: no..  on executing that query  get output as empty column

Comment: SELECT        1 AS Expr1
FROM            Production
WHERE        (LocalCol = '2016-04-18 11:51:00 AM ')  this query show output 1 1 1 1 1.........          on executing this  SELECT 1 FROM Production WHERE LocalCol = '2016-04-18 11:56:29 AM '           ouput is empty

Comment: in where condition, only date should consider right not time??

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, LocalCol is of type DateTime; with that said, it will also be storing milliseconds. Your first query might be affecting rows fortunately because of 00 milliseconds. Please check the data and change query accordingly. You can try:

```
UPDATE       Production
SET          mylocalcol = '22/4/2016 06:13:55 AM'
WHERE        (LocalCol >='2016-04-18 11:56:29 AM' AND LocalCol <'2016-04-18 11:56:30 AM')
```